# selectInput resetting without reason

Tags: r, shiny

When I use the content of a `selectInput` to show something, it does not work properly: first it works, but instantly it resets the `selectInput`.

I'm using R version 3.5.0 and Shiny 1.2.0.

Here is a minimalist example to reproduce the behavior:

```
simpleList <- list("..." = -1, "A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Test", uiOutput("test"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("pole", "Pôle", choices = simpleList),
      h3(paste0("Pôle : ", poleChoisi()))
    )
  })
  
  poleChoisi <- reactive({
    if("pole" %in% names(input))
      return(input$pole)
    else
      return("...")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think I'm doing something wrong, but I don't get it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Best,

ChoCChoK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that `selectInput` is part of your `renderUI` call. Every time you update your h3 tag your `selectInput` is re-rendered.

Please see the following:

```
library(shiny)

simpleList <- list("..." = -1, "A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Test", selectInput("pole", "Pôle", choices = simpleList), uiOutput("test"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      h3(paste0("Pôle : ", poleChoisi()))
    )
  })
  
  poleChoisi <- reactive({
    if("pole" %in% names(input))
      return(input$pole)
    else
      return("...")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```